# 2D array using scanner, input ; Name Age Gender and to find the Oldest Person

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

something like this but using 2D array to input Name, age, gender and to find the oldest person that the user inputted.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);

do {
    System.out.println("Current list is " + list);
    System.out.println("Add more? (y/n)");
    if (stdin.next().startsWith("y")) {
        System.out.println("Enter : ");
        list.add(stdin.next());
    } else {
        break;
    }
} while (true);

System.out.println("List is " + list);
String[] arr = list.toArray(new String[0]);
System.out.println("Array is " + Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Comment: when i input john 16 male, jade 13 girl then find the oldest person and the out put is 

the oldest person is john "16" male

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Should create a `Person` class which will have properties like `age`, `name`, `gender` and should implement `Comparable` interface.

**Person class**

```
class Person implements Comparable{
    String name;
    String gender;
    int age;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }
    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object arg0) {
        Person p = (Person)arg0;
        return p.getAge() - this.getAge();
    }


}
```

**Main class**

```
List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<Person>();

    while(true) {
        Person p =new Person();
        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter name :");
        p.setName(stdin.next());
        System.out.println("Enter gender :");
        p.setGender(stdin.next());
        System.out.println("Enter age :");
        p.setAge(stdin.nextInt());
        personList.add(p);
        System.out.println("Do you want to add more ?(Y/N)");
        if(stdin.next().equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
            break;
        }
    }
    Collections.sort(personList);
    System.out.println("The oldest person is " + personList.get(0).getName());
```